# IPTables: connexion refused with MySQL (10061)

Tags: mysql, connection

Before asking I've read this first: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/access-denied.html
First try:

```
~# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u uu DBNAME -p
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 3296
Server version: 5.5.37-MariaDB-1~wheezy-log mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle, Monty Program Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [DBNAME]> Bye

~# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u uu DBNAME -p
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

So it's listening on port 3306. Now let's see my network config:

```
~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:ae:52:cd:71:d6
          inet addr:62.210.129.132  Bcast:62.210.129.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
blabla

~#
```

So let's try with the right working port but not 127.0.0.1:

```
~# mysql -h 62.210.129.132 -P 3306 -u uu DBNAME -p
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

So I've tried to fix it with:

```
MariaDB [DBNAME]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBNAME TO 'uu'@'62.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'XX';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [DBNAME]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBNAME.* TO 'uu'@'62.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'XX';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [DBNAME]> Bye
~# mysql -h 62.210.129.132 -u uu DBNAME -p
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '62.210.129.132' (111)
~#

~# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u uu DBNAME -p
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

... blabla
```

I've checked the table user as well:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select user, host, password from user;
+------------------+----------------+--------------------+
| user             | host           | password           |
+------------------+----------------+--------------------+
| [skipping root ]                                       |
| uu               | localhost      | *C5E430FB96FF191AF |
| uu               | 62.210.129.132 | *C5E430FB96FF191AF |
| uu               | 62.%           | *C5E430FB96FF191AF |
+------------------+----------------+--------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]>
```

So not working. So I'm wondering whether it comes from my ip policy or from the mysql server policy. Here's the iptables policy:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1143 packets, 131K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 56 packets, 2938 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 236 packets, 17506 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 236 packets, 17506 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1   211 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       62.210.129.132       0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 852 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

What am I missing, where should I look?

Comment: What are  IP/mask of the client? Ah now I get that you are using only one machine

Comment: It's local (remote ssh and launching mysql from linux command line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/446843/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-111), I found the solution.
It turned out I just had to comment the `bind-address` directive in my `my.cnf` file:

```
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
```

Then it works.